# Does the ignition point of flammable substances changes when provided a pure oxygen atmosphere?

Tags: physical-chemistry, combustion

I'm wondering if autoignition point decreases for substances when provided higher oxygen concentration.

Answer (score 2):

No, but because of a technical point.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoignition_temperature): *The autoignition temperature or kindling point of a substance is the lowest temperature at which it will spontaneously ignite in normal atmosphere without an external source of ignition, such as a flame or spark.*

So the definition of the **autoignition temperature** is based on air not pure oxygen.

For the **ignition temperature** in general the Wikipedia reference goes on: *The temperature at which a chemical will ignite decreases as the pressure or oxygen concentration increases.*